# How to access dataframe returned by UDF inside column in Spark Streaming

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing code to perform step detection on streaming sensor data. To do so I separate all incoming values as sensor parameters. After that I detect the steps with a UDF. Inside this UDF I create a dict to store two lists of important timestamps per determined step.

```
@udf(StructType())
def detect_steps(timestamp, x, y, z):
   .....   
   d = dict()
   d['timestamp_ic'] = times_ic
   d['timestamp_to'] = timestamp_to
   ......
   return d
```

In the Spark main function I created a dataframe that calculates all these steps in a sliding window like so:

```
stepData = LLLData \
        .withWatermark("time", "10 seconds") \
        .groupBy(
            window("time", windowDuration="5 seconds",slideDuration="1 second"),
            "sensor"
        ) \
        .agg(
            collect_list("time").alias("time_window"),
            collect_list(sensorData.Acceleration_x).alias("Acceleration_x_window"),
            collect_list(sensorData.Acceleration_y).alias("Acceleration_y_window"),
            collect_list(sensorData.Acceleration_z).alias("Acceleration_z_window"),           
        ) \
        .select(
            "window",
            "sensor",
            detect_steps("time_window", "Acceleration_x_window", "Acceleration_y_window", "Acceleration_z_window")
        )
```

Now, when I print the df schema it looks like this:

```
 |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- detect_steps("time_window", "Acceleration_x_window", "Acceleration_y_window", "Acceleration_z_window"): string (nullable = true)
```

While I want this:

```
 |-- window: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- sensor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_ic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_to: string (nullable = true)
```

However I cannot perform a select statement on the UDF column in stepData, error: `Column is not iterable`.

When I try to alter the root dataframe afterwards, by for example parsing the ic column to a spark dataframe like so:
`df_stepData = spark.createDataFrame(data=stepData.select("ic"))`
it gives me `TypeError: data is already a DataFrame`. 
Looking at the dataframe schema, however, `ic` is typed as string.
I've also tried to read `ic` as a json file, but that gives the following error:
`TypeError: path can be only string, list or RDD`

I could fix the problem by triggering the `detect_steps` UDF twice, the first one returning `timestamp_ic` and the second one returning `timestamp_to`, in order to get two columns but I'm sure there is a better, more efficient way.